# How do I load elements from a nested, comma separated JSON array into a SQL table

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a JSON array that I need to load into a SQL Server 2019 table. I'm having trouble with the language field which contains multiple values in square brackets, separated by commas. If I add the [0] key I can grab the first value, but I need all of the values in the field and the number of entries can vary. Removing the [0] ket just returns NULLs.

The JSON data is formatted like this:

```
{
"npi": "10009",
"type": "INDIVIDUAL",
"name": {
  "prefix": "",
  "first": "John",
  "middle": "S",
  "last": "Smith",
  "suffix": ""
},
"addresses": [
  {
    "address": "91820 SE Oak Rd",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "Dundee",
    "state": "OR",
    "zip": "97555",
    "phone": "8558675309"
  }
],
"specialty": [ "Family Medicine" ],
"accepting": "not accepting",
"gender": "Female",
"plans": [
  {
    "plan_id_type": "PLAN-ID",
    "plan_id": "717420005",
    "network_tier": "TIER-ONE",
    "years": [ 2021 ]
  },

  {
    "plan_id_type": "PLAN-ID",
    "plan_id": "71255203",
    "network_tier": "TIER-ONE",
    "years": [ 2021 ]
  }
],
"languages": [ "English", "EN (English)", "SP (Spanish)" ],
"last_updated_on": "2021-08-04" }
```

The T-sql that comes closest to what I need is

```
    Declare @ProviderDirCO varchar (max)
SELECT @ProviderDirCO=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\Transfer\Provider_Who.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
 --INSERT INTO Providers.ProviderDirCO
 SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.npi') as NPI,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.type') as type,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.prefix') as prefix,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.first') as first,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.middle') as middle,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.last') as last,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.suffix') as suffix,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.address') as address,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.address_2') as Address_2,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.city') as City,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.state') as State,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.zip') as Zip,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.phone') as Phone,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.specialty[0]' ) as Specialty,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.accepting') as Accepting,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.gender') as gender,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.languages[0]') as languages,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.last_updated_on') as last_updated_on,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.plan_id_type') as plan_id_type,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.plan_id') as plan_id,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.network_tier') as network_tier,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.years[0]') as years


    FROM OPENJSON(@ProviderDirCO ) as a
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value, '$.addresses') as b
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value, '$.plans') as c
```

How do I get all of the language type listed in the array to import into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to use JSON_QUERY instead of JSON_VALUE for the values that are in brackets.

```
    Declare @ProviderDirCO varchar (max)
SELECT @ProviderDirCO=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\Transfer\Provider_Who.json', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
 --INSERT INTO Providers.ProviderDirCO
 SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.npi') as NPI,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.type') as type,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.prefix') as prefix,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.first') as first,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.middle') as middle,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.last') as last,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name.suffix') as suffix,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.address') as address,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.address_2') as Address_2,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.city') as City,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.state') as State,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.zip') as Zip,
    JSON_VALUE(b.value, '$.phone') as Phone,
    JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.specialty' ) as Specialty,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.accepting') as Accepting,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.gender') as gender,
    JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.languages') as languages,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.last_updated_on') as last_updated_on,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.plan_id_type') as plan_id_type,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.plan_id') as plan_id,
    JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.network_tier') as network_tier,
    JSON_QUERY(c.value, '$.years') as years


    FROM OPENJSON(@ProviderDirCO ) as a
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value, '$.addresses') as b
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.value, '$.plans') as c
```

Brackets columns are now returned.

[image]